# Why odt file can not be opened by zip but can be opened by open office?

Tags: zip

I think odt files are ziped files.

Why odt file can not be opened by zip but can be opened by open office?

And a zip file not complete can also be unziped??

Who is familiar with zip format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i found the file is doc format, but saved as odt.
This file is searched by google.

Answer (score 5):

ODT files may or may not be zipped. It could also be a plain basic XML file (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDocument#Specifications).

Also, there are several versions of the ZIP file format that may or may not inter-operate well, so maybe it's just your ZIP utility not being able to read the particular format your ODT file uses.

Answer (score 2):

Rename the file's extension to `zip`. In that case, it should open with the zip unarchiver (tested with 7-Zip, PowerArchiver, Total Commander).

The problem seems to lie with the archivers' extension sniffing: PowerArchiver (albeit an old, old version) had problems opening the file when the extension was `odt`, but worked fine with `zip`.

Of course, the file extension `odt` will probably be associated with OpenOffice, so double-clicking the file will start OpenOffice.

Comment: Can not be opened by all zip tools,but can be opened by open office.

Comment: @bruce dou: Yes, you said that in the question. Can you give us some more details?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [7zip](http://7-zip.org/) for .odt, If those are zip files, supposed to able to open.

`a zip file not complete`, you mean broken zip files?, its depends on how its damage. even you can open it, you will not get desired results.

Answer (score -2):

odt files are open office document text files.

Comment: Yes they are. But the ODT format says that the data may be stored as a zipped archive, and most of the ODT files I've seen are stored that way.

Comment: never mind, my brain just got back from holiday. Sorry for the unhelpful reply.