# Docutils: Does rst2html copy images?

Tags: python, markup, docutils

Does rst2html copy image directories and image paths?

I tried rst2odt and it copies the images. I failed to reach the same for rst2html.

It's crazy. It is a tool for documentation and yet I am searching for hours to find a definitive answer to such a central question.

Comment: Where do you expect them to be copied?  rST documents don't include images, only links, so I wouldn't expect HTML documents to contain them either.

Comment: I wouldn't call _rst2html_ "a tool for documentation" either.  It's a quick converter.  For a full-fledged documentation tool, take a look at [Sphinx](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/)

Answer (score 0):

The reStructuredText markup language
includes the [`image` directive](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#image),
as do documentation generators built on reStructuredText such as
[Sphinx](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/basics.html?#images).
How the image is included in the output
depends on the output format.

For example, the `rst2odt` program does not copy image directories or image paths,
it copies the actual images into the ODT file.
[ODT files are just ZIP files with a particular structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838719/why-odt-file-can-not-be-opened-by-zip-but-can-be-opened-by-open-office),
so you can unzip the ODT file and see the images in `Pictures/`.

By contrast, the `rst2html` program does not store images directly in the HTML file
as this is not typical of HTML.
Instead, it [generates](https://repo.or.cz/docutils.git/blob/d13674baf375b15d9fdc9bacc9c7148950ff3670:/docutils/docutils/writers/_html_base.py#l909)
an [`img` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Img)
that points to the image.
For example, this markup:

```
.. image:: example.png
```

will produce this HTML:

```
<img alt="example.png" src="example.png" />
```

The path `example.png` is an example of a path relative to the source file,
but [there are other options for img tags](http://www.tech-evangelist.com/2008/10/05/file-paths/).

If you want to embed the images directly into the HTML file as e.g.
[data URLs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs),
you will need to do something else, such as:

1. Manually convert the image to Base64, use it to make an HTML img tag with the data URL, and include it in the reStructuredText using the
   [raw directive](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#raw-data-pass-through).

   For example, this markup:

   ```
   .. raw:: html

       <img alt="red square" src="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGQAAABkAQMAAABKLAcXAAAAA1BMVEX/AAAZ4gk3AAAAFElEQVQ4 y2NgGAWjYBSMglFATwAABXgAASlxufwAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" />
   ```

   will produce this HTML:

   ```
   <img alt="red square" src="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGQAAABkAQMAAABKLAcXAAAAA1BMVEX/AAAZ4gk3AAAAFElEQVQ4 y2NgGAWjYBSMglFATwAABXgAASlxufwAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" />
   ```

   which will produce this image:

   [image: red square]
2. Use a tool such as [SingleFile](https://github.com/gildas-lormeau/SingleFile),
   [inliner](https://github.com/remy/inliner),
   or [webpage2html](https://github.com/zTrix/webpage2html)
   to [post-process the generated HTML](https://meta.caspershire.net/the-case-for-single-html/).

Note there are limitations on data URLs, including
[browser-dependent size restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12637395/what-is-the-size-limit-of-a-base64-dataurl-image).

Related:

- [Creating a self contained, offline HTML5 app and the best method for embedding its resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068256/creating-a-self-contained-offline-html5-app-and-the-best-method-for-embedding-i)
- [How to create MHTML standalone file with same page links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102712/how-to-create-mhtml-standalone-file-with-same-page-links)
- [How to save html pages as one file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16169744/how-to-save-html-pages-as-one-file)
- [What's the best "file format" for saving complete web pages (images, etc.) in a single archive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260058/whats-the-best-file-format-for-saving-complete-web-pages-images-etc-in-a)
- [How to provide a web site as a single file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46379586/how-to-provide-a-web-site-as-a-single-file)
- [Embedding Base64 Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207190/embedding-base64-images)
- [How to display Base64 images in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499633/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html)
- [Should I embed images as data/base64 in CSS or HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258057/should-i-embed-images-as-data-base64-in-css-or-html)
- [Data protocol URL size limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695151/data-protocol-url-size-limitations)
- http://www.techerator.com/2011/12/how-to-embed-images-directly-into-your-html/
- https://www.davidbcalhoun.com/2011/when-to-base64-encode-images-and-when-not-to/

Answer (score 0):

Since Docutils 0.18, the "html5 writer" supports
several ways of image handling.

You can embed images in the HTML output with
`rst2html5 --image-loading=embed INFILE > OUTFILE.html` or set the "image-loading" option
in a configuration file (cf. https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/user/config.html#image-loading)